# how to listen both udp and tcp from the same port?

Tags: netcat, socat

I am using socat

server - >    `socat TCP-LISTEN:4444 STDOUT || socat UDP:LISTEN:4444 STDOUT`

client - >   `socat - UDP:localhost:4444`

When I try to connect with udp, I cannot connect, but it happens with tcp.   what should I do? ,where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look of the socat man page shows UDP:LISTEN doesn't make sense.

It looks like you want:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:4444 STDOUT || socat UDP-LISTEN:4444 STDOUT`

You have a typo, colon instead of hyphen.

Comment: "It looks like you want" means that the following line is the correct code.